# Finding generators for an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

We know that $\Bbb{Z}$ is Noetherian. Hence, we can conclude that $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is Noetherian, too. Consider the ideal generated by $\langle 2x^2+2,3x^3+3,5x^5+5,…,px^p+p,…\rangle$ for all prime natural numbers $p$. How can I determine a finite number of elements which generate this ideal? Clearly the Euclidean algorithm is not valid in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

$$ (1 - 11 x - x^2 + 5 x^3 - 5 x^4) (2 x^2 + 2) + 4 (1 + x) (3 x^3 + 3) - 
 2 (1 - x) (5 x^5 + 5) = 4$$
$$-112 (1 - x^3 - x^5) (5 x^5 + 5) - 80 (x + x^3) (7 x^7 + 7) + \\
 187 (1 - x^3 + x^6 - x^9) (3 x^3 + 3) + 51 x (11 x^{11} + 11) = x+1$$

Conversely,
$2x^2+2 = 2(x+1)(x-1)+4$, $px^p+p = p(x+1)(1-x+\dots + x^{p-1})$ for $p$ odd.

Comment: @ronno- I think you just needed $-112(1-x^3-x^5)\dots=x+1$.

Comment: $p$ and $(1-x+\dots+x^{p-1})$ would anyway be there in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Did you miss the 'Conversely'? Or are you saying $4$ is not needed?

Comment: @algebraically_speaking I realize, almost a decade later, that you just wanted to find a subset of the generators which generates the same ideal, whereas I was trying to find a minimal set of generators, namely $(x + 1, 4)$. It is plausible that $x^2 + 2, x^3 + 3, \dots, x^{11} + 11$ is also minimal, but this is less obvious.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Use the Euclidian Algorithm in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, then multiply whatever what you get by the common denominator. If needed.

**Edit** By the extended EA we have

$$3x^3+3=\frac{3}{2}x (2x^2+2)+3-3x$$
$$2x^2+2=-\frac{2}{3}(-3x+3)+4$$

Therefore 
$$4=2x^2+2+\frac{2}{3}(3x^3+3-\frac{3}{2}x (2x^2+2))\\
=(2x^2+2)(x-1)+\frac{2}{3}(3x^3+3)$$

This shows that $12 \in I$.

Now, for each $p \neq 2,3$ we can write $1=12m+pn$, and hence

$$x^p+1=12(x^p+1)m+n(px^p+1) \in I$$

Using again the Euclidian algorithm in $Q[x]$ we get
$$x^7+1=x^2(x^5+1)+(-x^2+1)$$
$$x^5+1=(-x^2+1)(-x^3-x)+x+1$$
$$-x^2+1=(x+1)(-x+1)$$

Thus, $x+1$ is a linear combination of $x^5+1$ and $x^7+1$ with all the coefficients in $Z[X]$. Moreover, as it divides $px^p+p$ for all $p \neq 2$, it is trivial to show

$$I=(2x^2+2, x+1) \,.$$

Now, use again the Euclidean algorithm,  for those two polynomials to get
$$4=2x^2+2-2(x-1)(x+1)$$

Comment: @user26857 No. I ssugest you use the Euclidian algorithm in $Q(X)$ to prove that some constant $a \in \mathbb \Z$ can be written as a linear combination of $px^p+p$ and $qx^q+q$.... Then, for any $p \nmid a$ you can show that $x^p+1 \in I$, by writing $1$ as a linear combination of $p$ and $a$.

Comment: @user26857 Added my complete answer.... And you question contains the answer: you get something simple when $p,q$ are both ODD, but nothing more.. So how can you get the extra info? ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably overkill, but it may help you to look into Gröbner bases. They are "good" generators for polynomial ideals, in the sense that they allow you to easily decide ideal membership with a division algorithm, and are minimal in this respect. They are typically defined for polynomial rings over a field, but as I recall, can be calculated for polynomial rings over the integers.

Comment: As I state in my answer, a Gröbner basis can be computed for ideals of $\mathbb Z[x]$, in fact, [for polynomial ideals over any Euclidean domain](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717188800208).
I'm not readily aware how the modified version of Buchberger's algorithm can be used to tackle OP's ideal, since I'm very rusty from 6 years outside the field. Such an ideal typically yields a pattern very quickly after starting the algorithm.
I posted my answer, partly in response to the question's title and to help future visitors understand the ideals of $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

> The arguments of the following proof relies on computations within $\mathbb Z[x]$ without any reference to bigger rings.

Let $I=\langle 2x^2+2,3x^3+3,5x^5+5,\dots,px^p+p,\dots\rangle$. Since $$px^p+p=p(x^p+1)=p(x+1)(x^{p-1}-\cdots+1)$$ for any prime $p\ge 3$, we have $$I\subseteq \langle 2x^2+2,x+1\rangle.$$ For $2x^2+2=2(x+1)(x-1)+4$ we get $\langle 2x^2+2,x+1\rangle=\langle 4,x+1\rangle$. Now let's prove that $4,x+1\in I$ and then conclude

> $$I=\langle 4,x+1\rangle.$$

Note that $$3(x^3+1)=3(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ $$5(x^5+1)=5(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)=5(x+1)[x^2(x^2-x+1)-x+1],$$ and therefore $15x^2(x^3+1)-15(x^5+1)=15(x^2-1)$. Since $15\cdot2(x^2+1)-30(x^2-1)=60$ we get $60=4\cdot3\cdot 5\in I$. Repeating the same procedure with $11$ and $13$ instead of $3$ and $5$ we get $4\cdot11\cdot13\in I$, and since $(3\cdot5,11\cdot13)=1$ we find $4\in I$.

It remains to prove $x+1\in I$: since $2x^2+2\in I$ and $4\in I$ we get $2x^2-2\in I$ and summing up $4x^2\in I$. Since $3x^3+3\in I$ and $4x^3\in I$ we get (by subtraction) $x^3-3\in I$, so $x^3+1\in I$. From $5x^5+5=5x^2(x^3+1)-5x^2+5\in I$ we get $5x^2-1=(5x^2-5)+4\in I$. Now recall that $4x^2\in I$, so $x^2-1\in I$ and using $x^3+1\in I$ we get $x+1\in I$.